# Is it possible to decide in polynomial time if a poset is a subposet of another which is given ?

Tags: algorithms, order-theory, graph-theory

I am reading some theory on partial orders and I wonder something which perhaps has a simple answer : Given two partial orders $G_1,G_2$ (by their hasse diagrams), is it possible to know in polynomial-time if it exists a injective order-preserving map from $G_1$ to $G_2$ ? (that is to say a function $f : G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ wich is injective and such that $\forall x,y, x< y  \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)$)

We can easily solve the problem in exponential-time (and it is in NP, of course) but I don't find neither a better algorithm neither literature about this. Is this an already-know problem and do we have something about this ?

Thanks

Comment: It closely resembles the NP-complete subgraph isomorphism problem.

Comment: Indeed. If you could build such an algorithm you could use it on the following instances : "given any graph G, give the poset on $V(G) \cup E(G)$, where an element of $E(G)$ is larger than the two vertices to which it is incident.

Comment: Actually, the title is inconsistent with the wording of the question. If $f$ is required to be an isomorphic embedding (or at least injective), then the problem is NP-complete, as shown in Brendan’s answer. If it is only required to preserve the strict order as written, then the problem is solvable in polynomial time (or even NL): it is equivalent to asking whether the height of $G_1$ is at most the height of $G_2$.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I forgot to specify the injectivity of the function, sorry; it is fixed now.

Comment: To emphasize Emil's point: he is asking whether the OP really meant $\Rightarrow$, or instead should have written $\leftrightarrow$. 

Comment: Hum, perhaps I am missing something but I am not sure it is what Emil wanted to say. I think he just wants to be sure that the mapping doesn't assign two different elements of the first poset to the same element of the second one because in that case, it is indeed possible to solve the problem just by looking the height, as he said.

Comment: I was mainly worried about injectivity. Whether the mapping should reflect the order is in principle also relevant, but in the presence of injectivity it does not affect the answer (the subgraph isomorphism problem and the induced subraph isomorphism problem are both NP-complete, by a reduction from clique).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completing Emil's observation: Take any subgraph isomorphism problem (well known to be NP-complete).  Add a new vertex in the middle of each edge and then orient the new edges outwards from the new vertex.  That is, replace each undirected edge $x-y$ by $x\leftarrow z\rightarrow y$.  I think you get two posets (with two levels) for which the subposet problem is equivalent to the original.  So it is NP-complete.

ADDED: It makes no difference if we define "subgraph" and "subposet" as containing all relations within a given set of points (the "induced subgraph" interpretation).  Just take the smaller graph to be a clique and reduce from the NP-complete CLIQUE problem using the same construction.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this answer. Consider the graph $G$ consisting of three points and no edges, and $H$ consisting of four points, with two parallel edges. So $G$ is not isomorphic to any subgraph of $H$, but if we do your procedure, no new points are added to $G$, but $H$ gains two points on the lower level, and there is a copy of $G$ inside the new $H$ poset. So in this instance, the subposet problem was not equivalent to the original subgraph isomorphism problem.

Comment: Actually, in this case, G is isomorphic to the subgraph of any three points with no edge of H. We don't consider subgraph in the induced way, I think. That is to say : (E',V') is a subgraph of (E,V) if $E' \subset E$ and $V' \subset V$.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking induced subgraphs. This would be the same issue with $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ in your question. 

Comment: But given your reply, how about this case:  $G$ has five points a,b,c,d,e, with two edges ab and cd. And $H$ has four points, with three edges ab, bc, and cd. So $G$ is not a subgraph of $H$, since it has too many points. The poset of $G$ is two disjoint $V$s and a dot, and the poset of $H$ is like $VVV$. We can map the poset of $G$ into the poset of $H$, in the $\Rightarrow$ sense of your question, by mapping the $V$s to the outside, and using the middle bottom dot for the extra point.

Comment: A simpler counterexample:  let $G$ have three points and no edges, and let $H$ have two points and one edge. So $G$ is not a subgraph, but as a poset, it maps (vacuously) into any poset with at least three points.

Comment: I guess they don't need to be connected, but rather only to have no isolated points, since that would ensure that in the poset version, the levels are respected. So I guess you could just add another point connected to everybody before you start, and then apply the transformation.

Comment:  Hum, I see... But this problem seems to be avoided if we considered only connected graphs (and the isomophism subgraphs problem for connected graphs is also NP-complete, isn't it ?)

Comment: Joel’s comment provides a reduction of the subgraph isomorphism problem to its special case for connected graphs, so yes, it is also NP-complete. (Another way to fix the original construction is to add a self-loop to each vertex.)

Comment: @joel One ought to really be thinking of Graded posets in this context. This type of problem comes up when you look at the face poset of a polyhedron (really a regular cell complex). One question that you could ask is what conditions on poset maps between face posets do you need to ensure that these poset maps are induced by maps of polyhedra. One trivial remark is that if the polyhedron maps are injective, then the grading on the posets must be preserved.